# How to find Accounts with multiple Contacts?

Tags: reporting

The SSN# is now an external ID on our Contacts. So we shouldn't have multiple ones w/ the same SSN#. But a great deal of Contacts were made before the SSN# was made an external field. So we have a bunch which already exist w/ the same SSN#.

I essentially want to purge one of each of the Contacts which share a SSN#. I'm thinking I'll do it through Data Loader. How can I produce a report showing only the Contacts which have another Contact w/ the same SSN# ?

There's much too many to just have a report grouped by the SSN# and check off the ones with a count of 2.

I have a feeling there's no easy way to do this ... ?

Comment: I would probably use Apex to do this, it would be significantly faster - create map<string, contact> in execute anonymous keying by the SSN..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not really looking for a report, but a way to clean up a mess. How I might do that is to write an anonymous script that I run repeatedly until it tells me I'm done:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT SSN__c ssn FROM Contact GROUP BY SSN__c HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1 LIMIT 1000];
Set<String> values = new Set<String>();
System.assert(results.size() > 0, 'All done!');
for(AggregateResult ar: results) {
    values.add((String)ar.get('ssn'));
}
Contact[] deletes = new Contact[0];
for(Contact record: [select ssn__c from contact where ssn__c = :values order by createddate asc]) {
    // Returns true if collection is modified
    if(!values.remove(record.ssn__c)) {
        deletes.add(record);
    }
}
delete deletes;
```

Run this in execute anonymous until you get a failed assertion that says "All Done!"

Or you could adjust this script to perform merges, instead.

---

Alternatively, setup a Duplicate Rule that performs an exact match on the field. All of your duplicates will then be flagged as such. From there, you can run reports, export the data, etc.

Just go to Setup > Data Management > Duplicate Management > Duplicate Record Sets > Matching Rules, and create a new rule.

---

Here's a basic merge script. Note that you can't merge in batch, so this code will likely not be able to merge more than about 210 records (I built in a safety buffer, but you might need to adjust based on the DML operations per trigger):

```
AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT SSN__c ssn FROM Contact GROUP BY SSN__c HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1 LIMIT 1000];
Set<String> values = new Set<String>();
System.assert(results.size() > 0, 'All done!');
for(AggregateResult ar: results) {
    values.add((String)ar.get('ssn'));
}
Map<String, Contact> masters = new Map<String, Contact>();
Map<String, Id[]> dupes = new Map<String, Id[]>();
for(Contact record: [select ssn__c from contact where ssn__c = :values order by createddate asc]) {
    // Returns true if collection is modified
    if(values.remove(record.ssn__c)) {
        masters.put(record.ssn__c, record);
        dupes.put(record.ssn__c, new Id[0]);
    } else {
        dupes.get(record.ssn__c).add(record.Id);
        if(dupes.get(record.ssn__c).size() == 2) {
            Database.merge(masters.get(record.ssn__c), dupes.get(record.ssn__c));
            dupes.get(record.ssn__c).clear();
            if(Limits.getDmlStatements()-10 > Limits.getLimitDmlStatements()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
for(String ssnKey: masters.keySet()) {
    if(!dupes.get(ssnKey).isEmpty()) {
        Database.merge(masters.get(ssnKey), dupes.get(ssnKey));
        if(Limits.getDmlStatements()-10 > Limits.getLimitDmlStatements()) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow - you could turn that into merge operation ? How could you do that ?

Comment: @Zoom_v Added an example merge script. Note that you may need to adjust the code to deal with DML statements/query limits, etc.

Comment: This is really awesome. Now, I know I'm going to come off like an idiot with this : I guess I need to write test code in order to deploy ? And how would I run it ? Do I need to make it a after update trigger and just update records w/ Data Loader ? I really appreciate it any help. You've helped me so many times on here !

Comment: @Zoom_v This is written as an execute anonymous script. Just go to "Your Name" > Developer Console > Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window, put the code in there, and run. No unit tests required. You will need to run the code repeatedly until there's no more results (System.AssertException: All Done!), but beats having to do anything manually.

Comment: I got an "Illegal assignment from Map<Id,List<Id>> to Map<String,List<Id>>" error for line 8. I changed the map to "Map<String, Id>. It then gave me an error for line 17 : "Method does not exist or incorrect signature : void merge (Id, List <Id>) from the type database. 

I don't know if the error on line 8 was actually fixed by putting in a String. I just changed it to that as a guess.

Comment: @Zoom_v Yeah, I typed it freehand. I just mocked this up in my developer org for real. Hope this helps. Again, you'll need to manipulate the "-10" so that you don't hit governor limits.